# SQL Join with twice the same table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join

I have this table:

```
 CREATE TABLE EMP
    (EMPNO NUMBER(4) CONSTRAINT EMP_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY ,
    ENAME varchar2(10),
    JOB varchar2(9),
    MGR NUMBER(4)CONSTRAINT EMP_SELF_KEY REFERENCES EMP (EMPNO),
    HIREDATE DATE,
    CONSTRAINT EMP_FOREIGN_KEY REFERENCES DEPT (DEPTNO));
```

And now i want to get the name (ename), job (job), and the name of the manager (mgr) of all workers.

I thought about doing this with a join on the same table:

```
SELECT ename, job, empno
FROM emp
INNER JOIN emp AS emp1
ON (emp.mgr = emp1.empno);
```

But i allways get the error: "missing keyword"

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to remove `AS` from the inner join statement:

```
SELECT emp.ename, emp.job, emp.empno
FROM emp
INNER JOIN emp  emp1
ON (emp.mgr = emp1.empno);
```

And you have to add the alias before each column name.

Comment: Woah :) thanks for the qoicjk response but it still doesn't work. Now I get a other error: "Collumn not unique defined"

Comment: @Bajellor Then change `FROM emp` to `FROM emp emp`

Comment: Jep this was the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: @Bajellor: *That* was the problem? The table's name is `emp`, but you are forced to use an alias `emp` for it??? Jens' query would run in any Oracle version I know of. Which version are you using?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Didn't mean it like this, his idea of using an alias gave me the hint and now it works. I have called my aliases emp1 and emp2 :D

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT E2.ename, E2.job, E2.empno, E1.ename as 'manager_name'
FROM emp as E1
INNER JOIN emp AS E2
ON E1.mgr = E2.empno;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.ename, e.job, e.empno
FROM emp e
INNER JOIN emp e1
   ON (e.mgr = e1.empno);
```